# Fast powers of two with floating exponent [C]

Tags: c, math

Essentially, I'm trying to use the values calculated in the code below, but when I storing the values in all the objects that have their own rates is adding just enough bytes to cause a cache miss. And using a lookup table obviously doesn't help matters.

So I'm looking for a way to get these values faster than with the standard power functions, are there any tricks I can use due to the possible inputs being very restricted?

```
static inline
double __attribute(( pure )) get_decay_rate(uint8_t rate)
{
     if(rate >= 128)
     {
          return 65535.0/65536.0;
     }

     double k = pow(2, rate/8.0);
     return (k - 1.0) / k;
}


/* pseudocode:
     double k = (int) pow(2, k/8.0);
     k = (k - 1) / k;
     return log(65535/65536)/log(k);
*/
static inline
uint16_t __attribute(( pure )) get_decay_modulus(uint8_t rate)
{
     if(rate <= 128)
     {
          return 1;
     }
//turns out to be the same as the above pseudocode, for some reason. 
     return pow(2, (rate - 128) / 8.0);
}
```

Comment: And you also tried putting a static 256-long array in each function? Or a static 128-long array?

Comment: do you mean `rate / 8.0` in `int k = pow(2, k/8.0);`? similarly in `get_decay_modulus` you refer to `k` without declaring it

Comment: @Hurkyl As the problem is cache misses, then that will mean less code can fit in the cache, so it moves the problem rather than solving it.

Comment: @oldrinb yeah, i did mean that.

Comment: (rate -128) / 8 is this intended to be integer division?

Comment: @samgak, no that was another mistake, fixed now.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll change my answer then

Comment: What about a look up table with 8 entries? Is that small enough?

Comment: Also, why not use floats?

Comment: @samgak 8 entries would be small enough, but i'm not sure how you'd do it.  I need doubles because the 6 decimals of precision given by floats isn't enough.   Although it may be possible to store it as 32 bit numbers because the exponents are basically unused.

Comment: @Patrick: He said he was storing things in objects, not in a nice compact table; it shuffles the situation around, but it's not clear that the problem remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this line:

```
double k = pow(2, rate/8.0);
```

Basically what you are doing here is raising 2 to the power of a fixed point number.

You can make use of the fact that pow(a, b+c) = pow(a, b) * pow(a, c), and a non-integer number = integer part + fractional part. So you calculate pow with the integral part of your fixed point number and multiply that with pow of the fractional part.

Store the 8 fractional exponents in a lookup table:

```
double fractionalPowersOf2[8];

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    fractionalPowersOf2[i] = pow(2.0, i / 8.0);
```

Then you can do your calculation like this:

```
double k = (double)(1 << (rate >> 3)) * fractionalPowersOf2[rate & 7];
```

This masks out the fractional part and uses it for a table lookup, then multiplies that by 2 raised to the power of the integral part using bitshifts. If the cast to double is too slow you can use a lookup table for that too.

You might also be able to use some fancy bitmagic type approach where you use your value as the exponent of a double by casting pointers etc but this will not be portable.

Edit: as pointed out by user3386109 in a comment, if you turn on optimizations the compiler may optimize raising 2 to the power of an integer value for you, so this code may be faster:

```
 double k = pow(2,rate>>3) * table[rate&7];
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that is perfect!

Comment: @samgak Given `double k = pow(2,rate>>3) * table[rate&7];` with optimizations enabled, the compiler will do the fancy bit magic on the exponent for you.

Comment: @user3386109: I'd be worried about whether the semantics *really* allow the fancy bit magic -- and skeptical that it won't perform magic with the integer calculation. In any case, `ldexp` is probably the better function to use here if you insist on invoking a floating point function. (profiling needed!)